# como puedo conseguir que se ejecute en el backend una solicitud get cada 24 horas?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Disculpen mi novatada, quiero hacer que mi método envié una solicitud get cada 24 horas para actualizar la base de datos y verificar si un cliente excedió los 30 días de registro, como puedo lograr esto? debería hacer esta funcionalidad desde el back o desde la base de datos? cosas que investigue y estaba pensando implementar: websockets con un intervalo de tiempo. PD: estoy iniciando recién en el backend, capaz y noten algún error, me gustaría que me enseñen que hice mal.

```
//Retorna cuantos días suscripto esta el cliente
public long daysOfSus(Client cl) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate clientDate = cl.getFecha_registro();
    return today.toEpochDay() - clientDate.toEpochDay();
}


//Actualiza la tabla en función si una subscription está activa o no.
public ArrayList<Client> updateClient() {
    ArrayList<Client> updatedClients = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Client> clientes = (ArrayList<Client>) clientRepository.findAll();

    for (Client cli : clientes) {
        // Si la suscripción ha expirado
        if (daysOfSus(cli) >= 30) {
            cli.setExpirated(true);
            updatedClients.add(cli);
        } else {
            cli.setExpirated(false);
            updatedClients.add(cli);
        }
    }
    return (ArrayList<Client>) clientRepository.saveAll(updatedClients);
}
```

Comment: Quizás un  `cron job` en el server que ejecute ese código cada día a las 00 horas. Quizás un campo en la tabla donde tengas la fecha exacta de cuándo hará dicha solicitud y cuando se realize, se ejecute un update para el siguiente mes. WebSockets obliga a mantener la conexión, ¿y si el cliente no se conecta? ¿qué haces?. Saludos.

Comment: Si tienes una aplicación SpringBoot donde está ese trozo de código solo tienes que usar @Scheduled. [Aquí](https://www.aluracursos.com/blog/programando-tareas-con-scheduled-de-spring--amp) puedes encontrar un ejemplo. No entiendo bien a qué te refieres con usar WebSockets en este contexto.